# Insert multiple tables and multiple rows in one table

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns, rows

I need to insert multiple tables and multiple rows in one table.

Let's say have 3 tables

**1: Subjects Table**

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| ID |   Subject   | Class |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | English     |     1 |
|  2 | Mathematics |     1 |
|  3 | Sciences    |     1 |
|  4 | English     |     2 |
|  5 | Mathematics |     2 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

**2: Months Table**

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Month |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Oct   |
|  2 | Nov   |
|  3 | Desc  |
+----+-------+
```

**2: Users Table**

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | Name | ClassID |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | XerK |    1    |
|  2 | cdya |    1    |
|  3 | nija |    2    |
|  4 | Sara |    2    |
|  5 | Noda |    2    |
+----+------+---------+
```

Now I need to insert all this in this Table

**Results Table**

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | userID  |   subjectID    | MonthID  | Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 1(xerk) | 1(English)     | 1(oct)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  2 | 1(xerk) | 2(Mathematics) | 1(oct)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  3 | 1(xerk) | 3(Sciences)    | 1(oct)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  4 | 1(xerk) | 1(English)     | 2(nov)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  5 | 1(xerk) | 2(Mathematics) | 2(nov)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  6 | 1(xerk) | 3(Sciences)    | 2(nov)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  7 | 1(xerk) | 1(English)     | 3(desc) | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  8 | 1(xerk) | 2(Mathematics) | 3(desc) | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
|  9 | 4(Sara) | 3(Sciences)    | 3(desc) | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 10 | 4(Sara) | 4(English)     | 1(oct)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 11 | 4(Sara) | 5(Mathematics) | 1(oct)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 12 | 4(Sara) | 4(English)     | 2(nov)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 13 | 4(Sara) | 5(Mathematics) | 2(nov)  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 14 | 4(Sara) | 4(English)     | 3(desc) | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 15 | 4(Sara) | 5(Mathematics) | 3(desc) | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
+----+---------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How  can I insert all this by one button in page PHP?
Need to insert every user have subjectID and MonthID.

**Solution**

```
INSERT INTO results 
    (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6)
SELECT 
    users.Col1, subjects.Col2, months.Col3, 0, 0, 0
FROM
    (SELECT Col1 FROM users) as users
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT Col2 FROM subjects) as subjects
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT Col3 FROM months) as months
```

I found my answer but I need to insert new member data without duplicates old members in results table.

Comment: The point of SO is to **help** you to find a solution to a question, not to do the entire work from scratch instead of you. Pls share what you have tried so far (include your code) to solve your question and what went wrong with it.

Comment: I found **solution** right now but I need insert new member data without duplicates old members in results table Thanks

Comment: What you're saying isn't clear. Did you find the answer to this already, or do you have a different question?

Comment: I find the answer now i need different question

Comment: If you have a new question, then post it as a new question. Although in this particular case I would urge you to search SO before asking because this question is asked on a daily basis, therefore has an answer.